# Issue creating a div using Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a div, that is being appended to another div. Seems to be working but, the ruby code is not recognized and the image tag does not load:

```
function add_event(event)
{
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML='<%= image_tag("events_pics/band.png", :class=> "event_pic_small") %><h6 class="event_info">Event_1: Frame: 974</h6><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right " href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>';
    div.className='user_event my_background';
    $("#event_list").append(div);

}
```

Plus I would like to assign a function on the `<i class="icon-remove"></i>` so, is there a more elegant way to create that div?

Comment: You cannot run Ruby code from inside JavaScript code; it makes no sense. You could pre-process the JavaScript source on the server, or you could simply make the `<img>` tag with JavaScript (much better).

Comment: oh ok I have forgotten about that

Comment: @Pointy yes you can. Name your file js.erb and  the javascript that is getting returned to the browser will be rendered first by erb.

Comment: @Nobita Yes, but that is definitely not the same as "running Ruby code from inside JavaScript".  By the time that the JavaScript code runs, the Ruby code is gone.

Comment: I will prolly use simple img tags. Any ideas on how to assign a function to the "<i class="icon-remove"></i>" ??

Comment: Since you apparently are using jQuery anyway, it's really easy, but you might want to ask in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You realize that Javascript execute AFTER server code (Rails) have produce the response.

That is why the image_tag is not recognized.

Basically, you cannot use <%= xxx %> in a javascirpt file since those markup are recognized by rails server side and are processed before the response is sent back to the browser. Then your javascript code start.